# How to replace data in a file

Tags: python

This is driving me crazy. I have a file which has 3 lines in it like:

```
==== Table ====
 
)))|(% style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle" %)(((
```

All I want to do is to change it to this:

```
==== Table ====
)))
|(% style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle" %)(((
```

I have tried:

```
with open('1.html', 'r') as reading :
    data = reading.read().split('\n')
    text = "==== Table ====\n )))"
    data = data.replace('==== Table ====)))', text.split('\n'))
    with open('1.html', 'w') as replaceData:
        replaceData.write(data)
```

Comment: Pease post what you have tried.  Generally, to change a file, read the whole thing into memory, make a change to the string, write it back out again.

Comment: just edited....

Comment: so you just want to insert a newline somewhere?

Comment: Your replace line doesn't make much sense... You basically want `data.replace("==== Table ====\n\n)))", "==== Table ====\n)))\n")`...

Comment: And you should de-indent the `with` statement for writing to be ***outside*** the one for reading...